# Clean accented character and white space in column in Talend

Tags: replace, talend

I have a workflow as follows. In the column 'summary', i want to remove

1. question mark(?)
2. white space from the text
3. replace accented alphabets with the english equivalent. For example é into     e.

[image]

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

> Removing question mark(?)

In your tMap, use `StringHandling.EREPLACE(row.yourString,"?","")`

> white space from the text

In your tMap, use `StringHandling.TRIM("row.yourString")`

> replace accented alphabets with the english equivalent. For example é
>   into e.

In your tMap, use `TalendString.removeAccents(row.yourString)`

You don't have to import additionnal librairies with TalendString class already implemented.

Basically all these functions (and much more) are accessible through the Expression Builder in tMap.

Comment: TalendString.removeAccents(row.yourString) will simply remove é and it will not convert it to e

Comment: Just use it, you'll see that it does replace "é" with "e". Check the code in the java routine to be sure.

Comment: I did try and it is not doing the required conversion

Answer (score 0):

see my answer on [Talend community forum](https://community.talend.com/t5/Design-and-Development/Clean-accented-character-and-white-space-in-column/m-p/22994#U22994)

[image]
1st, load the commons-lang3-3.4.jar file and import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.
For that, in tLibraryLoad Basic settings select "commons-lang3-3.4.jar", then in Advanced setting enter import "org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;" in the import field.
In tJavaRow, enter the following (maybe something similar in tMap depending on your use case):
`output_row.line = StringUtils.stripAccents(input_row.line);`
tFixedFlowInput is here to generate data for the flow ("aaaéééàààçççbbbb" for my example), and the result is:
`aaaeeeaaacccbbbb`
Hope this helps,
TRF

Comment: Thanks TRF! You are one of the few in Talend community who is always there to help everyone!! I do have one more question though and i posted it in talend forum too. How should i connect tLibraryLoad and tJavaRow in my workflow? should it be as follows? Please suggest if i should arrange this palettes in different way.
 
tMap -> tLibraryLoad -> tJavaRow -> tFileOutputDelimited

Comment: Usually, place the tLibraryLoad at the bebenning of the job.
In my example, because there is nothing else inthe job, it's the 1st component and the following tFixedFlowInput is connected with a trigger onSubjobOk (or onComponentOk).

Don't forget to indicate the topic as solved (if it's)